# Boost.Python and Qt inheritance

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, boost-python

I'm want to wrap my C++ code wrote with Qt framework into python with boost.python. But I really can't understand one issue : when I wrapping class, I should also wrap it's base class. So should I wrap QObject, for example, if class which I need to wrap inherits from it?
e.g. :

```
class TRIKCONTROL_EXPORT BatteryInterface : public QObject, public DeviceInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    /// Returns current battery voltage in volts.
    virtual float readVoltage() = 0;

    /// Returns current raw reading of battery.
    virtual float readRawDataVoltage() = 0;
};
```

UPD 1 : Now I'm pretty sure that I don't need to wrap c++ QObject, but I don't know, how to tell my wrapped class to inherit from PyQt QObject. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Excuse me, but I'm not sure that I had understood you. How can PyQt help me in this case? Of course, in future I'm planning to use pyqt for signal/slot usage in my project, but now I'm need to wrap c++ Qt code to use it with python.